# How numpy percentile calculates value in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
m = np.percentile(a, 50)
print(m)
```

how numpy percentile function calculates the value for the array!!

Comment: check documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Answer (score 1):

This is quite clear in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

> **q**: array_like of float
>   Percentile or sequence of percentiles to compute, which must be between 0 and 100 inclusive.

So this is giving you the `50th` percentile of the distrubution of the data, or the `2nd` quantile:

```
a = np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.percentile(a, 50)
# 3.5
```

Which is basically the median:

```
np.median(a)
# 3.5
```

Comment: You'll find the logic [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/91118b3363b636f932f7ff6748d8259e9eb2c23a/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3846). But the idea is to find the kth value (proportional to the array's length), of the sorted array (making use of partition for efficiency). And there's a step of averaging a value with the one that follows if the corresponding index is a whole number @Kishan